# Calculate determinant without using the rule of sarrus or the method of minors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Calculate the determinant of the following matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a+x & b & c \\
a & b+x & c \\
a & b & c+x \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

without using the rule of sarrus or minors

I got the answer using this property multiple times:
 $$
\begin{pmatrix}
a+x & b & c \\
a & b+x & c \\
a & b & c+x \\
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
x & b & c \\
0 & b+x & c \\
0 & b & c+x \\
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
a & b+x & c \\
a & b & c+x \\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

but that got very tedious and long for higher dimensions

The answer is:
$$ x^2(a+b+c+x) $$

Comment: What you show is "a general rule": to use the multilinearity of the determinant. Why not better to write "to develop this determinant without using 1,2,3,4,5,6 ", or better: to develop it using this or that *only* ? Foggy instructions bring foggy answers, misunderstandings, etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio By a general rule, I mean a method for calculating any kind of determinant. Using the rule I show above I can solve this particular determinant, but not all.

Comment: @Msegade For the general approach lookup the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of a matrix.

Comment: @Mse That's false: the determinant function is **always** multilinear, no matter what the order of the matrix, how many zero entries or over what field the matrix is defined. Again, that is as a "General rule" as one can expect, so again: you better specify in a very detailed way what you want, or else people can begin calculating in different, wild ways.

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not saying the rule does not apply to all determinants. I'm saying that aplying that rule doesn't always leads you to the answer ( the numeric value of the determinant) in a general matrix. I'm fine with wild ways of solving this problem :)

Comment: @Msegade **Once again**, you are wrong: multilinearity will **always** lead to a matrix with the very same determinant as the original one. That it will be easier, messier or ugly is another matter.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, I don't want to argue, I edited the question with the two methods I know to calculating determinants "generally".

Answer (score 4):

The determinant is quite obviously a $3^{rd}$ degree monic polynomial $P(x)$. By inspection $x=0$ must be a double root since all the rows become equal and the matrix degenerates to rank $1$. The remaining root can be guessed as $x=-a-b-c$ by noticing that the sum of all columns becomes $0$. Therefore $P(x) = x^2(x+a+b+c)$.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant you seek is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $-A$, where
$$ A = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ a & b & c \\ a & b & c \end{array}\right)
$$

This matrix has at most one linearly independent row, so at least two of the three eigenvalues are $0$ from which we conclude that the characteristic polynomial of $-A$ is of the form $x^2 (x-r)$ where $r$ is the remaining eigenvalue of $-A$.

Since all but one of the eigenvalues is zero, it is also correct to say that $r$ is the *sum* of the eigenvalues of $-A$.  The sum of the eigenvalues of a square matrix is the *trace* of the matrix, and it's a standard result that the trace is equal to the sum of the diagonal elements.

So the trace of $-A$ is $-(a+b+c)$ and the characteristic polynomial of $-A$ is therefore $x^2 (x+a+b+c)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$det
\begin{pmatrix}
a+x & b & c \\
a & b+x & c \\
a & b & c+x \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
row1=row 1-row3
$$
det\begin{pmatrix}
x & 0 & -x \\
a & b+x & c \\
a & b & c+x \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
row2=row2-row3
$$det
\begin{pmatrix}
x & 0 & -x \\
0 & x & -x \\
a & b & c+x \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
colum3=colum1+colum2+colum3
$$det
\begin{pmatrix}
x & 0 & 0 \\
0 & x & 0\\
a & b & a+b+c+x \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
finally we have
$$(a+b+c+x)det
\begin{pmatrix}
x & 0 \\
0 & x \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
given the result wanted.
$$x^2(a+b+c+x)
$$

Comment: Careful: this may enter under the definition of "general rule" the OP meant...or not, of course.

Comment: sorry, i miis that detail

Comment: @juliogodoy  Thats a good answer